# angularjs: ajax website using Ruby On Rails not crawling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, angularjs, seo, bots

I am trying to make an angularjs site crawl-able.To do that i am using ?_escaped_fragment= solution as suggested by Google.

For example:

When google sees request with hash fragment like `"http://xample.com/#!/Home"` ,it convert the url into `"http://xample.com/?_escaped_fragement_=/Home"`.

I have implemented `Index controller` in rails that accepts such request and redirect that request to `crawler controller` which in turn provide dynamically generated HTML snapshot to the Google.

However except my home page `http://xample.com/` 
no other pages are getting crawled.(maybe because of hashbang)

Below are the url that are not crawled even after implementing ?_escaped_fragment_= solution as suggested by google:-

```
http://xample.com/#!/Home
http://xample.com/#!/xyz
http://xample.com/#!/abc
http://xample.com/#!/def
```

Controllers Used by me:-

`Index controller` accepts Url with "?_escaped_fragment_="

```
    class IndexController < ApplicationController
      def index()
        if params['_escaped_fragment_'] == '/Home'
          redirect_to :controller=>'crawler', :action => 'crawlhome'
          return
        elsif params['_escaped_fragment_'] == '/Xyz'
         redirect_to :controller=>'crawler', :action => 'crawlxyz'
          return
        end
 elsif params['_escaped_fragment_'] == '/abc'
         redirect_to :controller=>'crawler', :action => 'crawlabc'
          return
        end
    end

 elsif params['_escaped_fragment_'] == '/def'
         redirect_to :controller=>'crawler', :action => 'crawldef'
          return
        end
end
```

---

Crawler controller

```
    class CrawlerController < ApplicationController
      layout false
      require 'net/http'
      require 'uri'
      def crawlhome
      @data = "getting data from api and displaying same data in view"
      end

      def crawlXyz
      @data = "getting data from api and displaying same data in view"
      end

       def crawlabc
      @data = "getting data from api and displaying same data in view"
      end

   def crawldef
      @data = "getting data from api and displaying same data in view"
      end
    end
```

The Seo concerned person working in my company suggested to me to implement the website without `hashbang`(push state) in the url.Is this the right solution for the problem.

This however does not work in the non-Html browsers.

What might be the problem with implementing `http://xample.com/#!/Home`.Why is it not crawling in the above case.

I have tried many different solutions from the forum but still not giving me the proper results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually The above code is working.Google started crawling after 4 days(long time)..Thought there was mistake in the code.

Hope this will be helpful to other developers.